# HashMap.containsKey not working for some reason

Tags: java, hashmap, containskey

I wonder why the logic `if (!map.containsKey("Africa"))` neither go to if block (XX) nor else block (YY)

```
public class HashMapWithListTest {

public static void main (String args[]) {
    HashMap<String,List<String>> map=new HashMap<String,List<String>>();

    //to put data firs time
    String country="USA";
    //create list for cities
    List<String> cityList=new ArrayList<String>();
    //then fill list
    cityList.add("New York");
    cityList.add("Los Angeles ");
    cityList.add("Chicago");

    //lets put this data to map
    map.put(country, cityList);

    //same thind with other data
    country="Pakistan";
    cityList=new ArrayList<String>();
    cityList.add("Lahore");
    cityList.add("Karachi");
    map.put(country, cityList);

    country="Malaysia";
    cityList=new ArrayList<String>();
    cityList.add("Kuala Lumpur");
    cityList.add("Johor Baru");
    map.put(country, cityList);

    country="Indonesia";
    cityList=new ArrayList<String>();
    cityList.add("Jakarta");
    cityList.add("Bandung");
    map.put(country, cityList);

    //now lets check what is in map
    System.out.println(map);

    //to add city in USA
    //you need to get List of cities and add new one 
    map.get("USA").add("Washington");

    //to get all values from USA
    System.out.println("city in USA:");
    List<String> tmp=map.get("USA");
    for (String city:tmp)
        System.out.println(city);

    System.out.println("x------------------x");
    map.remove("USA");
    System.out.println(map);
    System.out.println("x------------------x");
    map.get("Indonesia").add("Lembang");
    System.out.println(map.get("Indonesia"));
    System.out.println("x------------------x");
    country="Indonesia";
    cityList=new ArrayList<String>();
    cityList.add("Semarang");
    cityList.add("Bali");
    map.putIfAbsent(country, cityList);

    if (!map.containsKey("Africa")) {
        System.out.println(map.get("XX"));
    } else {
        System.out.println(map.get("YY"));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't execute the if statement? It should print "null" regardless of the condition, since neither of they keys XX and YY appear in your map.

Comment: When did `Africa` become a country?

Comment: I suggest you step through the code in your debugger to get a better understanding of what it is doing.

Comment: @PeterLawrey It didn't that's why it isn't in the map :P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map.containsKey("Africa")` returns `false` in your code (because there is no such key in your `HashMap`) and then `map.get("XX")` produces `null` value (there is no value associated with `"XX"` key in your `HashMap`), which is printed by `System.out.println`.

Code is correct, possibly there is a semantics issue

Comment: no problem, mate. You're welcome :) I recommend you to use debugger - it is very easy to find any mistakes with its help

Answer (score 0):

Best way to check existence of a key:

```
Myobject value = map.get(key);
if (value != null) {
...
} else {
if (map.containsKey(key)) {
   // key exists but it's null
} else {
   // No such key
}
}
```

Because this is the way HashMap.containsKey works:

```
@Override
public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
Entry<K, V> m = getEntry(key);
return m != null;
}
```

Comment: So the best way is to duplicate the behavior of `containsKey`?

Comment: I just pointed how the containsKey works...The first code is just for better understanding and debugging of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

it is going in if loop..if you want to check, repace `System.out.println(map.get("XX"));` with `System.out.println("XX");`